# Storybook with Syncfusion

Tags: angular, storybook, syncfusion

I'm very new to Storybook. I'm trying to see whether I can create a Storybook app that exposes a set of controls, including all [Syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/) controls as well as further custom controls that will be written later on.

Has someone got experience with integrating an existing UI Library like [Syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/) with Storybook?

**UPDATE:** I figured out that you can use Storybook Decorators.

**So decorators:**

```
[moduleMetadata({ declarations: [ButtonComponent], imports: [ButtonModule]})]
```

The ButtonComponent contains the component that uses the [Syncfusion Button](https://www.syncfusion.com/javascript-ui-controls/js-button). The ButtonModule is the Syncfusion Button Module. Just posting this as a comment for now as I'm not sure if this the correct way to do it.

Comment: UPDATE: I figured out that you can use Storybook Decorators. So 
`decorators: [moduleMetadata({ declarations: [ButtonComponent], imports: [ButtonModule]})]`
The ButtonComponent contains the component that uses the Syncfusion Button. The ButtonModule is the Syncfusion Button Module. Just posting this as a comment for now as I'm not sure if this the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, our Syncfusion controls are compatible with the Storybook application. So, we can integrate the Syncfusion library into the Storybook application. We suggest you to follow the below steps to meet your requirements.

**Step 1**: Create a new Angular CLI application with our simple button component by following the documentation below.

**Documentation: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/button/getting-started/**

**Step 2**: In your Angular project directory, run this shell command to add the Storybook to your project.

```
npx sb init
```

**https://storybook.js.org/docs/angular/get-started/install**

Now you can find that the stories and storybook files are added to your project folder.

**Step 3**:  Create a sample **“.ts”** file in the **“./src/stories/ej2button.stories.ts”** folder and add the below scripts to this created file.

```js
import { Story, Meta } from '@storybook/angular/types-6-0';
import { ButtonComponent, Button } from '@syncfusion/ej2-angular-buttons';

export default {
  title: 'Example/SyncfusionEJ2Button',
  component: ButtonComponent,
  argTypes: {
    // backgroundColor: { control: 'color' },
  },
} as Meta;

const Template: Story<ButtonComponent> = (args: ButtonComponent) => ({
  component: ButtonComponent,
  props: args,
});

export const Primary = Template.bind({});
Primary.args = {
  cssClass: 'e-primary',
  content: 'Button',
};

export const Secondary = Template.bind({});
Secondary.args = {
  content: 'Button',
};
```

**Step 4**:  Also, create a **“.html”** file in the **“./storybook/preview-head.html”** folder and add the style CDN link in it.

```html
<link href=https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/material.css rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

**Step 5**: Run the below command to open the Storybook application in a browser window.

```
npm run storybook
```

Now we are able to see the storybook application will be rendered in the browser window.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcErL.png)

For your convenience, we have rendered the simple Button component in the storybook. You can download and use the sample from the following link.

**Sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/angular-storybook-grid1033353217**